# Is there a way to make the typescript compiler throw an error for invalid quoted properties?

Tags: typescript

The typescript compiler will tolerate invalid property names when the property name is quoted. For instance, in the following snippet, you can see that I am able to access and assign an invalid property by quoting it:

```
type ContactDetails = {
  "Email": string
  "HomeAddress": string
};

const UserContact: ContactDetails = {
  "Email": "foo@bar.com",
  "HomeAddress": "123 Main St"
};

// Throws an error, as it should, because PhoneNumber is not a 
// member of ContactDetails
const phone_A = UserContact.PhoneNumber;

// Throws NO error, but phone_b will be undefined. phone_b is not type safe.
const phone_b = UserContact["PhoneNumber"];

// Throws NO error, and phone_c will equal "123-456-7891"
UserContact["Phone Number"] = "123-456-7891"
const phone_c = UserContact["PhoneNumber"];
```

Quoted property access makes it difficult to trust the type safety of the language as a whole. For instance, consider the following function:

```
function sendReminderEmail(UserContact: ContactDetails, Message: Email) {
  const recipient = UserContact["Email"];
  const subject = Message.Subject;
  const body = Message.Body;
  sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

Let's suppose this function is valid on the day it is written by Alice. But then, imagine a year later, Bob changes the type definition of ContactDetails to eliminate the property `Email` and replace it with two properties, `WorkEmail` and `PersonalEmail`. The compiler will not detect that Bob has just broken Alice's function, and it will be shipped to production, where email reminders will suddenly start failing silently.

I suppose one answer is to just never use quoted property access, and perhaps have a linter rule to enforce this, but this strikes me as the linter doing something that should be the compiler's job. And besides, sometimes it's hard to avoid quoted properties, because you might be modeling external data that includes spaces like `external_db_row["Email Address"]`.

Is there any way to force the compiler into a stricter mode, where it will detect errors for quoted properties?

Comment: Your example gives me "User is not defined" when put in a [playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0n5nw).

Comment: Also... when I correct your example [here](https://tsplay.dev/mZXb1w)... I get errors (lots of them, in fact). Is your TSConfig just too loose? Show us your TSConfig. Rest assured there is no way obvious mistakes like this will be not be caught by the compiler if used correctly. It's pretty dang smart :)

Comment: Looks like you're just not using `--strict` for some reason.   With `--noImplicitAny` (which is part of `--strict`) you get the expected errors.  Are you intending not to use `--strict`?

Comment: Thank you for recommending `--noImplicitAny` that is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained by @jcalz above, quoted property names create an "implicit any." This behavior can be forbidden with compiler options by setting the following in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true
  }
}
```

For the example I gave above, this would result in the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"PhoneNumber"' can't be used to index type 'ContactDetails'. Property 'PhoneNumber' does not exist on type 'ContactDetails'.
```